# using cast in sql in libre office base

Tags: sql, ms-access, libreoffice-base

I am using libreOffice Base to query an external (access.mdb) database which is predefined and cannot be altered. This is because I get a new database every day and have to create reports based on the included data.

In this database on row is declared as varchar(50) but the values are digital(10,2) and i need those values to calculate some results.

Now I am trying to cast the row into an new digital row, but it fails:

```
select cast(´myVal´,digital[10,2]) as numVal from ´myTable´
```

myVal is as mentioned above defined to be varchar[50]

Can anyone tell me how the right syntax for the cast works?

Comment: How does it fail, what error do you get?

Comment: Hi Mark, Base tells me the syntax is wrong. But its an very simple errormessage with no more details.

Comment: Take a look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8EBB0E94-2D43-4975-BB13-87AC8D1A2202 ; as far as I'm aware `digital(10, 2)` is not an access data type.

Comment: Base tells me: SQL-Status: 3000
Error-Code: -2147467259

Comment: which syntax do i have to use the access syntax or the base syntax

Comment: As far as I know, you need to use the syntax of the database system you access: so the Microsoft Access syntax.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried an cast to varchar(50) or varchar with the same result

Comment: that's an good hint

Comment: That is because Access doesn't have `CAST`, you need to use the conversion functions listed in the link I posted in my second comment (at least, I think so, it has been a while since I have done anything with Access).

Answer (score 0):

With the Hint of Mark I found the right syntax. Its the Syntax of the database system I accessed - means in this case the syntax from the access.mdb

So the right syntax is:

```
select clng(´myVal´) as numVal from ´myTable´
```